# What logging system I use?

Tags: java, log4j, slf4j, logback, apache-commons-logging

How to determine, what logging system given project uses?

It has signs of `log4j`, `slf4j`and `logback`. Looks like active config file is `log4j.properties`. The loggers are created in classes by

```
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);
```

the full type of logger is `org.slf4j.Logger` and the type of factory is `org.slf4j.LoggerFactory`.

But there are also jars `logback-core-0.9.26.jar` and `logback-classic-0.9.26.jar`.

Other jars are `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar`, `slf4j-api-1.6.1.jar`, `log4j-1.2.16.jar` and `commons-logging-1.1.1.jar`.

What defines that `logback` is apparently inactive? How to activate it?

Comment: Look for ALL slf4j jars.  It may be bridging log4j to slf4j

Comment: Also check the exact Classpath. Not all jars may be in it

Comment: "the type of factory is org.slf4j.LoggerFactory" < That's wrong class to print the name of, see my answer below for correct class name to print.

Comment: If both logback-classic.jar and slf4j-log4j12.jar are really present on the class path, then SLF4J will print a warning message of the console. However, you have not mentioned any such message.

Answer (score 2):

sl4j is a facade, there is no actual implementation. In other words sl4j cannot work alone, underlying logging framework can be log4j, logback, java util logging and so on.

`slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar` dependency implies that the underlying logging implementation is log4j.

Advantage of this approach is that later on you can switch your logging implementation from Log4j to logback(which is claimed to be better by many) or any other logging framework. Your classes are not tightly coupled to logging framework.

Answer (score 1):

Given the jars you mentioned, I assume the logging system is log4j, accessed through either slf4j or commons logging (maybe provided to satisfy other frameworks' dependencies).

The key here is `slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar` which instradates slf4j through log4j.

Comment: commons is also a facade, like slf4j?

Comment: ©suzan-cioc yes, it's using log4j directly.

Answer (score 1):

The situation you describe where both logback-classic.jar and slf4j-log4j12.jar are present on the class path is an instance of the "[multiple-bindings problem](http://slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings)" mentioned in the SLF4J error code documentation. The explication for the relevant error code states:

> The warning emitted by SLF4J is just that, a warning. Even when
>   multiple bindings are present, SLF4J will pick one logging
>   framework/implementation and bind with it. The way SLF4J picks a
>   binding is determined by the JVM and for all practical purposes should
>   be considered random. As of version 1.6.6, SLF4J will name the
>   framework/implementation class it is actually bound to.

Strangely enough you did not mention this error message in your question. If as you say both logback-classic.jar and slf4j-log4j12.jar are really present on the class path, then SLF4J will definitely print "Multiple bindings were found on the class path" as a warning.  If it does not, then only one binding is actually present on the class path.

Answer (score 1):

If project code uses slf4j, then asking what logging system it uses is asking a wrong question, in a way. It will use whatever logging framework slf4j finds *at runtime*. If you are unsure, turn on debugging information on all the relevant libraries:

- For log4j, add `-Dlog4j.debug` to java command line.
- For slf4j I remember adding debug code and there printing the class name of [ILoggerFactory](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/ILoggerFactory.html) instance (returned by [LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()](http://www.slf4j.org/apidocs/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.html#getILoggerFactory%28%29)), which reveals what actual logger it will use.
- Not sure how to debug logback or commons logging, but I'm sure their docs tell that.